# openshift: Is it possible to create directory in the filesystem of other gear?

Tags: filesystems, openshift, mkdir

Imagine a 3 gear scallable openshift account. Gear 1 has a php app and gear two has a php app for gear 1 app administration. Now I need to create a file in gear 1 from app in gear two. I am passing the OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR of gear 1 to the mkdir function in gear 2 but i see the error "No such file or directory".

My question is: can a app in gear x create dir in filesystem of gear y? If so, how to do that or how to configure that?

Thanks

Nat

Answer (score 1):

No, an app in gear x cannot create dir in filesystem of gear y because you cannot cross the boundaries between linux containers.

For more information, refer to the following link:
https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-filesystem.html